# How to exclude a certain field when summing up PromQl

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a query `example_query`

I summarize it by certain labels via `by (name, value)` like:

`sum(example_query[1m]) by (name, value)`

Let  label I have 3 names:

- 1
- 2
- 3

That is, I can specify
`example_query{value="1"}, example_query{value="2"}, etc`.

When summarizing. I want `value=3` to be ignored. How can I achieve this?

I tried using `without`, but grafana gives an error

Comment: `sum(example_query{value!="3"}[1m]) by (name, value)`

Comment: It's genius and useful. Thank you!